# Deseo quitar los 0 innecesarios de un string que representa un número

Tags: c#

Como dije, el programa debe tomar
a y b, calcular sus inversos, sumarlos, calcular el inverso de la suma y mostrarlo
en un label.
Sin embargo, también los 0 a la izquierda deben ser erradicados, si ingreso 1000, lo inverso a 0001, que es 1. Esto en los términos lo hace sin problema, pero en el resultado no, si ingreso por ejemplo, 305 y 794, me queda 0001 en vez de 1. Como lo arreglo? Por cierto, debajo esta mi código perfectamente funcional, pero con esto faltante.

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
    string num2 = Console.ReadLine();

    string num1reves = "";
    string num2reves = ""; 
    string sumastringreves = "";
    
    int inum1;
    int inum2;
    int isuma;

    for (inum1 = num1.Length-1; inum1 >= 0; inum1--)
    {
      num1reves+=num1[inum1];
    }
    for (inum2 = num2.Length-1; inum2 >= 0; inum2--)
    {
      num2reves+=num2[inum2];
    }
    int num1revesint = int.Parse(num1reves);
    int num2revesint = int.Parse(num2reves);

    int suma = num1revesint+num2revesint;

    string sumastring = suma.ToString();

    for (isuma = sumastring.Length-1; isuma >= 0; isuma--)
    {
      sumastringreves+=sumastring[isuma];
    }
    Console.Write(sumastringreves);
  }
}
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo mejorar tu pregunta, el problema en si es como remover los ceros de adelante de un string y no conocer todo el ejercicio. Puedes mejorar el titulo tambien eso ayuda que alguien lo vea y se anime a responder ya que sería algo más específico.

Answer (score 0):

Algo rápido debido a que **sumastringreves** es un string, puede usar la funcion .TrimStart() y remover los ceros de adelante, algo asi:

```
sumastringreves=sumastringreves.TrimStart('0');
Console.Write(sumastringreves);
```

Pero si trabajarías con enteros lo ideal es que lo conviertas y ya no se mostrarían los ceros de adelante.

Comment: Mil gracias, he convertido a int ```sumastringreves```  y me ha quedado así

```for (isuma = sumastring.Length-1; isuma >= 0; isuma--)
{
  sumastringreves+=sumastring[isuma];
}
int stringrevesint = int.Parse(sumastringreves);
Console.Write(stringrevesint);
```
Ya probé 305 y 794, y funciona. Puede parecer tonto, pero para asegurarme, desde ahora va a funcionar perfectamente con todas las posibilidades? Y por cierto, hay alguna diferencia entre esto y el trim que pueda o no afectar?

Comment: La unica diferencia es el tipo de dato